# Double number converted to string missing last digits

Tags: android, json, xamarin, double, xamarin.android

I have an Entity which contains property Latitude. This latitude I fetched from Foursquare API. It returned `"lat":21.010574093274126,"lng":105.82241065121046`

But in my `Xamarin.Android`, I debugged the Entity (after Deserialized Json), the `Latitud`e value of my `Entity` is just `21.0105740932741` (it missed `26` at the last)

But I tried to serialize my entity to JSON like this

```
var entityJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (entity);
```

the Latitude value after Serializing is now `21.010574093274126` (full number)

```
{
  "Id": 123,
  "Latitude": 21.010574093274126,
  "Longitude": 105.82241065121046,
}
```

Strange? So my question is how to get the exact Latitude when I use `Entity.Latitude.ToString()` still retains the full number as `21.010574093274126`

Thank you :)

Comment: Is there anything inconsistent with the theory that the debugger is truncating its output, but the value is really 21.010574093274126283859004615806043148040771484375 (the closest double to 21.010574093274126?

Comment: @patricia it's okey for me if it's only in debug but i set this value to string and it still displayed the truncated

Comment: Have you tried to deserialize the string back into Entity?

Comment: @skall steps are: get json string from api -> deserialized to entity -> cannot get the full double value to string -> then I tried serialize entity to string -> the deserialize string is now full of double value, so strange

Answer (score 0):

Json.NET uses [string format with "R" option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) which can result in inaccurate values.

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs#L291

Comment: But in my entity, I tried to set my Latitude to string, why was it not accurate? But when serialize my entity, the json string is display the accurate value? So the question here is: how can I use toString for my Latitude to get the accurate value ???